# Use GraphicsMagic with generator function and yield

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, yield, graphicsmagick

I'm generating a watermark in a png image with GraphicsMagic in NodeJs and then I want to upload to Aws S3 server, I have 2 functions the first to create the watermark  in the picture

```
function * createWatermark(watermark, text) {
    const textWidth = pixelWidth(text, { size: 37 });

    return gm('public/watermark/' + watermark)
    .size(function (err, size) {
        if (!err) {
            const width = size.width;
            const height = size.height;
            const marginBottom = 30;
            const marginRight = 60;

            //create first pattern
            return gm('public/watermark/' + watermark)
            .font("public/fonts/sofia/2E827A_2_0.ttf", 37)
            .fill('rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)')
            .drawText((width-textWidth-marginRight), (height-marginBottom), text)
            .write('public/img/temp/' + watermark, function(e){
                // console.log('done', e); // What would you like to do here?
                return e;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

the second function is to upload to picture to AWS S3 server

```
function * uploadCreatedWatermark(fiileName, author, withPattern, format){
    var pathFile = 'public/img/temp/' + fiileName;
    var watermarkReadStream = fs.createReadStream(pathFile);

    yield AWSService.uploadFormFileStreamToAWS(
        Env.get('AWS_WATERMARK_FOLDER') + '/' + format,
        author + (withPattern ? '_pattern' : '')+'.png',
        watermarkReadStream,
        {isRootPath: true}
    );
}
```

the second function was created 1 month ago for another developer, I only created the first function (to create the watermark in the png file).

From the main function I call both

```
class ExampleController {
    * foo(request, response) {
        var text = 'aaron  |  gallereplay';
        var author = 'aaron';

        var watermark = 'Cinemagraph_watermarks_1_1.png';
        yield createWatermark(watermark, text);
        yield uploadCreatedWatermark(watermark, author, false, '1_1');
    }
}
```

but it fails, because the first function is running before the second one ends and the png file does not yet exist

***Extra Info:***
1) My first Idea was put the second function into the first one, but that fail because the function doesn't exist

```
    function * createWatermark(watermark, text) {
    const textWidth = pixelWidth(text, { size: 37 });

    return gm('public/watermark/' + watermark)
    .size(function (err, size) {
        if (!err) {
            const width = size.width;
            const height = size.height;
            const marginBottom = 30;
            const marginRight = 60;

            //create first pattern
            return gm('public/watermark/' + watermark)
            .font("public/fonts/sofia/2E827A_2_0.ttf", 37)
            .fill('rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)')
            .drawText((width-textWidth-marginRight), (height-marginBottom), text)
            .write('public/img/temp/' + watermark, function(e){
                // console.log('done', e); // What would you like to do here?
                // return e;
                yield uploadCreatedWatermark(watermark, 'author', true, '1_1');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

2) both functions createWatermark and uploadCreatedWatermark is out of the class

```
class ExampleController() {
    * foo(request, response) { ... }
}
function * createWatermark() { ... }
function * uploadCreatedWatermark() { ... }
```

***PD:*** Sorry about my english, My main lenguage is Spanish